# Proving that $\mathbb{Z}_{n}$ is cyclic

Tags: group-theory

It should be very basic, but I'm struggling to understand the solution. I'm trying to prove that to group $\mathbb{Z}_{n}$ is cyclic. Everywhere I tried to find a solution I came across of the saying

> $\mathbb{Z}_{n}$ is cyclic because it has a generator $1$ (meaning $\mathbb{Z}_{n} = \langle 1 \rangle$).

I understand the meaning of generator, but I don't understand why the generator is $1$. Probably I'll feel stupid when I'll finally understand. Why $\mathbb{Z}_{n} = \langle 1 \rangle$ when $\mathbb{Z}_{n}$ is the Sum group of integers modulo $n$.

Comment: What is your definition of $\Bbb Z_n$?

Comment: @Arthur Sorry. I thought that it is a common name. I have edited.

Comment: It is a common name. But there are a few different definitions going around. How to prove that it is cyclic depends on which one _you_ are using.

Answer (score 1):

Take any $m\in\{1,2,...,n-1\}$. Then $m=1+1+...+1$ when you sum $m$ times. And if you take $m=0$ then $m=1+1+...+1$ when you sum $n$ times because $0\equiv n$(mod $n$). Hence any element of the group is generated by the set $\{1\}$.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* $a \bmod n = a(1 \bmod n)$.

Comment: It perhaps bears explicitly concluding that $1 \bmod n$ is thus a generator of the (cyclic) group $\mathbb Z \bmod n$.  The OP says, "I don't understand why the generator is $1$."  So you would not be giving away a secret, but rather giving an approach to clear up the OP's confusion.